# WebRTC renegotiation between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I am able to establish WebRTC connection between Firefox and Chrome, but renegotiation between Firefox-Chrome does not work properly.

There is no problem in renegotiation between Chrome-Chrome pair and Firefox-Firefox pair.

With Firefox-Chrome pair, when I start the renegotiation from chrome after removing or adding a track, renegotiation is successful and `onremovestream` or `onaddstream` callbacks are triggered on firefox correctly.

But when I start the renegotiation from Firefox after removing or adding a track using `pc.removeTrack` or `pc.addTrack`,  renegotiation was successful without any error. But in Chrome `onremovestream` or `onaddstream` callbacks are not triggered. When I get the MediaStream using `pc.getRemoteStreams` I can see that tracks' ids are changed after renegotiation, but MediaStream does not work when I tried to play it.

One odd thing I notice is, the actual local track id from Firefox does not match with the remote track id in Chrome (even before renegotiation).

Does Chrome and Firefox support renegotiation across the browsers(mainly from firefox to chrome)?

Have anyone achieved renegotiation between firefox and Chrome?

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You might want to post your update as an answer, even if unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: But that is not a solution. It is the reason for the problem. I am expecting an workaround for this problem.

Comment: Fair enough but I'm afraid you won't get it before Chrome also updates to UnifiedPlan

Comment: Yeah that is true. I was just hoping someone would find a complete solution of sdp-interop polyfill. You are right. I will post the update as an answer.

Comment: You're not forced to accept it though, this way, your question will still make its way into the "in need of an answer" streams, but you may also make it clearer for the ones than come after what the issue is, and that already deserve upvotes IMM.

Comment: Thank you. I moved the update as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete solution but the reason why this is happening. I encourage posting an solution if you find one.

There are two plans UnifiedPlan and PlanB for multiple streams in WebRTC. PlanB was dropped and UnifiedPlan is becoming the standard. Firefox implemented UnifiedPlan but chrome still has PlanB implementation. There is an [Chromium Bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465349) about this.

There was a polyfill written for this, [spd-interop](https://github.com/jitsi/sdp-interop). But this polyfill has a limitation, it supports only renegotiation from Chrome to Firefox.

If I find a workaround for this before chrome fixes the issue, I will update the answer.